# Visual studio code not save font-family

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open visual studio code, font(#editor.fontFamily) changing every time. 
My setting.json default, 
version information 
I use Windows 10.
any idea about it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I delete settings, this path %`UserFolder%\AppData\Roaming\Code` and delete the whole folder. then I delete all extension this path `%UserFolder%\.vscode`. it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You might have changed your Font Family in the Workspace Settings and not User Settings. Workspace Settings are local to your workspace and will not be applied for every/other workspaces.
Code -> Preferences -> Settings: Switch to the User Settings tab, change Font Family and **Save**

Comment: I changed both of but still not change ( I uninstalled then install again but still same)